# Laravel get my friend list query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database

I am using laravel to create a friend list. Now I want to get all of my friends with the name and avatar and stuff from the USER table.

My schema:

```
`cid`, `uid_by`, `uid_to`, `status`

uid_by (the inviting user)
uid_to (to be friend user)
status (accepted or ignored)
```

I only have 1 row per friendship. meaning its a 2 way friendship.

I tried to make a query:

```
    $contacts = DB::table('contacts')
                        ->leftJoin('users', 'contacts.uid_by', '=', 'users.uid')
                        ->where('uid_by', $me)
                        ->orWhere('uid_to', $me)
                        ->where('contacts.status', 'accepted')
                        ->get();
```

But its giving me some wrong information. Like instead of giving me the friend user info. its giving me my own info. All I want is to get the friends info.

Should I redesign the db? or am I missing something?

---

**update**

technically the thing is if uid_by is my user_id then check the uid_to else if the uid_by is not my user_id then check uid_by then use those to get the data from the users table uid column.

So my uid could be on uid_by and my friend on uid_to or vice versa.

But I can't get the query right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Advanced wheres](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres):

```
$contacts = DB::table('contacts')
 ->join('users', 'contacts.uid_by', '=', 'users.uid')
 ->where('users.uid','<>',$me)          
 ->where('contacts.status', 'accepted')                       
 ->where(function($query)
            {
                $query-->where('uid_by', $me)
                      ->orWhere('uid_to', $me)
            })

  ->get();
```

Comment: Tried this and it is still giving me my own data on some result. my friends id can either be on uid_by or uid_to. so if my id is in uid_by then my friends id is in uid_to. or if my id is in uid_to then my friends uid is in uid_by. So I need to know how to query that. thanks.

Comment: Wait, why are you doing a leftJoin?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at this. Care to elaborate?

Comment: What if you just exclude yourself? Updated.

Comment: But how? The query I am trying to make is suppose to get all my friends. then join it to the users so I can get the user data of my friends. Like I said the friends user_id can either be in uid_by or uid_to. So I have to know first w/c is mine so I can define the other is the id of my friend.

Comment: Now its not returning anything